# how to reorder a ggplot object with specific factor order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a pairwise heatmap in ggplot. I'm trying to avoid using other correlation plotting programs because of some downstream aesthetic changes that aren't supported the way they are in ggplot.

I can generate the desired plot with the default levels:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

mat <- round(cor(mtcars[,2:length(mtcars)]),2)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- NA
df <- melt(mat) %>% drop_na()
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

However, let's say that for some reason the order of these pairwise comparisons are relevant, and what I really need to plot is a different order. The way I've done this with other plots was to use `factor(df$x, levels = c("some", "particular", "order)`, but if I try something like that in this instance the tile orders of the plot are now also flipped.

```
mat <- round(cor(mtcars[,2:length(mtcars)]),2)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- NA
df <- melt(mat) %>% drop_na()
DesiredOrder <- c("cyl", "carb", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear")
df$Var1 <- factor(df$Var1, levels = DesiredOrder)
df$Var2 <- factor(df$Var2, levels = DesiredOrder)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

It seems like this problem is linked to the order of the matrix provided to the `dcast` command, but perhaps there is another way I can control the ultimate plotting order after the fact.

I'd appreciate any insights on a strategy to getting the plot order fixed, whether that be in a `ggplot` command or reordering something in the matrix prior to creating the data frame object passed into the plotting function.

Thanks

Comment: The order is fine; the "problem" is that you only select the lower triangle of the correlation matrix which itself was calculated with a particular order. You'd have to reorder the matrix rows and then take the lower triangle of that.

Comment: ok, thanks @joran; to reorder matrix rows with a vector of the order I want, like the `DesiredOrder` object in the example, it seems like `mat[order(DesiredOrder),] ` isn't doing the row reordering as I'd expected. Any ideas? 
thanks again

Comment: Will this do it `mat <- mtcars[, DesiredOrder]; mat <- round(cor(mat), 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest, you need to reorder the matrix and then take the lower triangle so the right observations are retained when you `gather` (`melt`). Here's a pipe version of your code, with the main addition being the reordering before dropping the lower triangle cells. Other changes include using `gather(na.rm = TRUE)` and `mutate_at` to save a couple lines.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mat <- round(cor(mtcars[,2:length(mtcars)]),2)
DesiredOrder <- c("cyl", "carb", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear")

mat %>%
  `[`(DesiredOrder, DesiredOrder) %>%
  `[<-`(lower.tri(.), NA) %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "var1") %>%
  gather(var2, value, -var1, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), ~ factor(., levels = DesiredOrder)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = value))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: For me, syntax such as ```%>% `[<-`()``` is very hard to read. Is there a more tidyverse-like way to write that?

Comment: If you want, you can use the `magrittr` [aliases](https://rdrr.io/cran/magrittr/man/aliases.html) `extract` and `inset`. I would reference them like `magrittr::extract` though, because otherwise you have to explicitly load `magrittr` and that has some name collisions. Honestly I just got used to using the backtick format after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Calum You's answer, except that I'd `gather` the matrix first, & use `filter` to remove rows corresponding to the lower triangle:

```
library(tidyverse)
mat <- round(cor(mtcars[,2:length(mtcars)]),2)
DesiredOrder <- c("cyl", "carb", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear")

mat %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "var1") %>%
  gather(var2, value, -var1) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), ~ factor(., levels = DesiredOrder)) %>%
  filter(as.integer(var1) <= as.integer(var2)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = value))
```

I believe the resulting plots should be the same, at least based on this example.

[image: plot]